# What's the best way To edit CSS and JS of Html Template

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a HTML5 Template in my Local Computer. I want to edit this template CSS and JS to use in my project. I use this solution to edit Template
Open Web site With Google Chrome also Open with Notepad++ Edit CSS file with Notepad++ and Refresh page in Google Chrome To View Change Result.
If there's any other method of doing so, please let me know.

Comment: you are using the correct way

Comment: @iam-decoder Thank You for answer this way Speed is too Slow for Big Project

Comment: @imanmir Big projects are supposed to be slow. If you're looking for a method that updates your changes in realtime, you'd need a dual monitor and some sort of system application that watches changes in the file and notifies Chrome to refresh.

Comment: @iam-decoder Google chorme not have Extention for Edit Page Css and save this change to file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Livereload](http://livereload.com/), it works great for me with [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en). You could also use [workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/workspaces) and edit in browser.

Comment: hopefully hes on a mac

Comment: @iam-decoder I use it on windows just fine.

Comment: I'll have to look into it again then, I remember only being able to find mac support for it. thanks @Dnwebdev